# Take value using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the html code i got :

```
<div id="bandeau">
            <div>
                <table border="0" align="left">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Désignation : </b>TAIE OREILLER VOLANT L63X63 IV</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Fournisseur : </b>0000036594 - AS'HABI</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Réf. fournisseur : </b>taie 63V ivoire</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><b>PCB : </b>20</td>
                        <td align="left"><b>SPCB : </b>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Type : </b>11 - PRODUIT SUIVI GD</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Univers : </b>010 - LINGE DE  MAISON</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Famille : </b>010 - LINGE DE LIT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Sous-famille : </b>025 - TAIE OREILLER/TAIE TRAVERSIN</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Segment : </b>005 - OREILLER</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Rayon : </b>LINGE DE LIT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Module : </b>VIP LINGE DE LIT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Volume PCB : </b>0,014720</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Packaging : </b>Carte interne/insert card</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"><b>Sensibilité : </b>Autre</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I wanna get the values assume to PCB (20) and Volume PCB (0,014720)

How can I do it using selenium on Python, i tried many ways but i never face this case.

Any idea ? I would appreciate

Thanks

here is the last code i tried

```
table_id = driver.find_elements_by_id('bandeau')
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_tag("tr") # get all of the rows in the table
for row in rows:
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]
    print(col.text)
```

i did that in order to get elements in table "bandeau" and take every rows in a list then sort and get what i want

i got this error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag'

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried the get by id to get a list but it returns this "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6dcfc2d0-8b5a-11e8-8987-e7cfe31b1b36", element=":wdc:1532008145346")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6dcfc2d0-8b5a-11e8-8987-e7cfe31b1b36", element=":wdc:1532008145347")>" i tried by tag and others. I'm a novice with selenium actually but the doc didn't help me that's why i posted here

Comment: Share exact code you've tried

Comment: @CyrilP , just replace `table_id = driver.find_elements_by_id('bandeau')` with `table_id = driver.find_element_by_id('bandeau')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this HTML : `<td align="left"><b>PCB : </b>20</td>`  , 20 is a text node. You can retrieve through Javascript executor.

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python+Selenium\\SO.html")

PCB = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[starts-with(., 'PCB')]")
text_node_pcb = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", PCB)
print('this is pcb text ' +text_node_pcb)

volume_pcb = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[starts-with(., 'Volume PCB : ')]")
text_node_volume_pcb = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", volume_pcb)
print('this is volume pcb text ' +text_node_volume_pcb)

#Now we willl iterate through the list and fetch all the texts.

table = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('b')
for i in range(len(table)):
 text_node = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", table[i])
 print(text_node)
```

Console output :

```
this is pcb text 20
this is volume pcb text 0,014720
TAIE OREILLER VOLANT L63X63 IV
0000036594 - AS'HABI
taie 63V ivoire
20
5
11 - PRODUIT SUIVI GD
010 - LINGE DE  MAISON
010 - LINGE DE LIT
025 - TAIE OREILLER/TAIE TRAVERSIN
005 - OREILLER
LINGE DE LIT
VIP LINGE DE LIT
0,014720
Carte interne/insert card
Autre
```

Hope this will help.

**Update** :

in case you are looking for text with their particular heading, you can just use this :

```
all_content_from_table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#bandeau table td')
for content in all_content_from_table:
 print(content.text)
```

in this case ,console output would be something like :

```
Désignation : TAIE OREILLER VOLANT L63X63 IV
Fournisseur : 0000036594 - AS'HABI
Réf. fournisseur : taie 63V ivoire
PCB : 20
SPCB : 5
Type : 11 - PRODUIT SUIVI GD
Univers : 010 - LINGE DE MAISON
Famille : 010 - LINGE DE LIT
Sous-famille : 025 - TAIE OREILLER/TAIE TRAVERSIN
Segment : 005 - OREILLER
Rayon : LINGE DE LIT
Module : VIP LINGE DE LIT
Volume PCB : 0,014720
Packaging : Carte interne/insert card
Sensibilité : Autre
```

Comment: try the code and let me know if you need any further explanation/clarification.

Comment: Nice, works perfecty ! Nice job ! And i understand what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Using `contains` and looking for specific text within the elements should allow you to filter for the elements you want.

```
table_id.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(text(), "PCB ")'].text
```

Comment: still the same error :/ "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_path' "

Comment: Try `find_elements_by_xpath` instead. I had a misspelling in there.

Comment: again, the problem is the list i created, i don't have any idea how to fix it actually. i'm counting and the ones who know

Comment: `table_id` is a list of elememnts. You cannot call `find_elements_by_xpath` for a list